# Will deleting a store delete all the products in it?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a multi store website in Magento.

If I delete a store will the products in that store also be deleted?

If a product is assigned to all the store what will happen?

Answer (score 1):

Product are not associated with stores (root categories are). Deleting store will leave both products and categories intact so don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete a store then `products in that store would not be deleted`.

But it will `remove the store id from the products`.

You will need to `index after you delete a store`

Comment: If I want to delete the products also what should I do?

Comment: If any product associated with delete store and other store,then it will be deleted